# SQL Query involving creating columns for displaying data

Tags: sql, sqlite, compare

I'm having difficulties creating a query on the following table:

```
Table Stats:
Column name       Type
_______________________________
STNAME            String
AREANAME          String
Population2010    Number
Population2011    Number
```

I'd like to list all the AREANAME for a particular STNAME, let's say STNAME = "NEVADA", and absolute change in population as of 2011 (POPULATION2011) compare to 2010 (POPULATION2010) for that AREANAME. The query should create a new column called "Result" that shows whether the change is an increase or decrease, something like this:

```
Name                Change    Result
Abberville City     100       Increase
Jefferson City      50        Decrease
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use something like the following which gets the change value between the `population2010` and `population2011` for each `areaname` and then uses a `CASE` expression to get the `result`:

```
select areaname,
  abs(population2010-population2011) Change,
  case 
    when population2010 > population2011
    then 'Decrease'
    else 'Increase'
  end Result
from stats
where stname = 'Nevada';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/023ef/1)